# How to parse this JSON containing single array

Tags: jquery

I am getting JSON in this format

```
[
    {
        "toppings": [
            "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
            "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
        ]
    }
]
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i get the elements present under the toppings ??

I have tried to parse this way , but giving me undefined .

```
for(var k=0;k<toppingres[0].length;k++)
          {

          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have an array and inner array is at its 0 index so you can get them this way:

```
$.each(data,function(index,item){

    $.each(item,function(index1,item1){
console.log(item1);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/56LgY/)

or:

```
$.each(data[0].toppings,function(index,item){
    console.log(item);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/XtF3E/)

or more simply:

```
console.log(data[0].toppings[0]);
console.log(data[0].toppings[1]);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/XVryR/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `toppingres` is the full object represented by the JSON, `toppingres[0]` isn't an array, so it has no `length`.

You mean to say:

```
var toppings = toppingres[0].toppings;

for ( var k = 0; k < toppings.length; ++k )
{
  var topping = toppings[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data=[
{
    "toppings": [
        "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
        "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
        ]
    }
];

// prevents duplicated object
$.each(data,function(index,item){
  console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWM7b/

and code:

`var myJSON = [{ "toppings": [
            "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
            "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
        ]}];
for (var i = 0; i < myJSON[0].toppings.length; i++){
    alert(myJSON[0].toppings[i]);
}`